# keyListener with Swing and game level system with Swing/keyListener and Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keylistener

I am a novice coder, have a tiny bit of experience with C++ about 10 years ago and now learning java (it's been about 4-5 months). I have a little collaborative project going, and I've got some things to figure out.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends JFrame {


    GamePanel panel;
    int[][] grid;
    int size;

    //...and some other variables

    public Game(String title) {

        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new GamePanel(grid,size);
        this.add(panel);

        Button button = new Button("WHAT");
        button.setBounds(-100, -100, 70, 70);
        this.add(button);
        button.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());

    }

    class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

            switch(keycode) {

                //arrow keys input and stuff

            }

            if(checkForWin())  //checkForWin() returns a boolean value for win/loss
                //won the game, thus end the thread here

            if(checkForLoss()) // similar stuff as checkForLoss()
                //lost the game, thus end the thread here

            //...update the panel
            panel.repaint();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Game me = new Game("GAME");

        me.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

So that's pretty much how the whole game thing looks like.

And I have questions:

1. I am using a button and put it at a negative position to make it invisible and using it as a mean of KeyListener. Is there any other way to add a key listener? ex) to the panel or something?
2. I want to change it so that each "level" is a thread and make it like

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args) {

       int level = 1;

       do {

           GameThread gt = new GameThread("Game");

           // run() will have the game constructor inside

           gt.setLevel(level);
           gt.start();
           gt.join();       //wait until the game "level" is finished

           if(won)
               level++;

           if(lost)
               level = 1;

       } while(!checkIfDonePlaying())

   }
   ```

Somewhat like this. I'm having trouble making the thread continue to run until the game level is actually finished. How do I do that?

3. I want to add a JLabel to show the score on the frame. But when I do that, the score doesn't update when I repaint() it. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your `GamePanel` class extend `JPanel`?

Comment: @TNT yes, it's a typical JPanel with paintcomponent and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for your first issue:

```
panel.setFocusable(true);
panel.addKeyListener(this);
```

Then you should just be able to do the usual key listener methods. Be sure to implement KeyListener!
Solutions for your other issues on their way. (Actually take @TNT 's suggestion and use keybindings, I'm more comfortable with listeners but for games I usually use lwjgl or slick2d)

2.

I feel that running your programs levels may be a bit inefficient (that may just be me) I would suggest having one thread in a run method and have the following:

```
Public void reset(int level)
 {
   //reset all variables based on local variable level...

}
```

Call it like this:

```
Reset(++currentLevel)); //use ++ before currentLevel so it adds to it and then resets
```

And you could easily use switch cases to do some special stuff if you want

```
Switch(level){
case 1: //...
}
```

And so forth. (I'm typing on mobile sorry for weird caps)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, and that reset thing sounds good to me. :)

Comment: Could you mark this the solution if you use it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Yes, there is a way to add a `KeyListener` to the panel, and that's by using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). For example:

   ```
   javax.swing.InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(panel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
   javax.swing.ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();

   im.put(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed UP"), "up");
   am.put("up", new javax.swing.AbstractAction() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
           // handle up arrow key action here
       }
   });
   ```
2. Swing is an event-driven environment, so do-while loops should not be used. Instead, use a Swing timer that periodically checks if your level has been completed.
3. Since you're not doing any custom painting on your `JLabel`, you shouldn't be using `repaint`. Instead, use its `setText` method.

Comment: This is something that I haven't heard of yet, but sounds like a plan. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you said I should check periodically. How often should I check?

Comment: However often as necessary; for example, you can set the delay to 1000ms or 10 even.